# Application of Taylor's Formula

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

If we are given that $f''(x) = f(x)$, how do we show that there exist constants $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x) = ae^x + be^{-x}$ for all $x$?

A hint is given: We can define another function $g$ by $g(x) = f(x) - ae^x - be^{-x}$, and choose constants $a$ and $b$ such that $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$. I don't really understand this hint, though... could anyone explain?

Comment: If you're just supposed to show it's possible, that's easy: $f'(x) = ae^x - be^{-x}$ and $f''(x) = ae^x + be^{-x}$.  First off, you didn't say $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$--those obviously solve the problem.  In fact, I think those are the only solutions because you might try to solve by factoring out $e^{-x}$: $e^{-x}\left(ae^{2x} - b\right) = 0 \rightarrow b = ae^{2x}$  The only way those are equal for all values of $x$ is if $a = b = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, I'm so sorry, the only specification in the problem was that $f''(x) = f'(x)$, not that they both equal 0. and that equality holds for all x.

Comment: @copper.hat Made final fixes to the problem... should really be more careful next time I type up these questions... hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: No problem, sometimes asking the right question is the important part :-)...

Answer (score 1):

If $f''=f'$, then $f(x)=a\mathrm{e}^x+b$, for some $a,b$ constant.

If $f''=f$, then $f(x)=a\mathrm{e}^x+b\mathrm{e}^{-x}$, for some $a,b$ constant.

The way to show it in the second case is:

$f''=f$ implies that $f''+f'=f'+f$ and hence $g=f'+f$ satisfies $g'=g$, which means that $g(x)=a\mathrm{e}^x$, and $f'+f=a\mathrm{e}^{x}$, and thus $$\mathrm{e}^x(f'+f)=a\mathrm{e}^{2x}$$
or
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^xf(x)\big)'=a\mathrm{e}^{2x},
$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

HINT : $g''(x)=g(x)-f(x)$

Second derivertive same $g-f$